# String.replace in a while loop never stops

Tags: python

I have a list of symbols that I want to replace by spaces in a string.
Here is my code:

```
useless = ['.', ',', '!', '?', ':', '(', ')', '"', '[', ']']
message = 'Whatever. you; "want:)'

for sign in useless:
    while message.find(sign):
        message.replace(sign, ' ')
```

This results in an infinite loop that never stops.
It's probably something easy but I'm on it for quite a long time now..
Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: `message = message.replace(sign, ' ')` string.replace does not operate in place, but returns the modified string as strings are immutable in Python.

Answer (score 5):

`message.replace()` doesn't modify the string (in Python, strings are immutable, which means that you can't modify them in-place).

What you're looking for is:

```
message = message.replace(sign, ' ')
```

(Also see Francisco Couzo's answer for another bug.)

Comment: That's it ! Both your and Francisco Couzo's answer below did it, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Besides having to reassign `message` to `mesage.replace(sign, ' ')`, `message.find(sign)` returns `-1` if it can't find the string, which is truthy.

Replace it with: `sign in message`.

Comment: Well spotted (+1).

Comment: Good point, also a "replacement" character at the start of the input message would exit prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regular expression instead of a loop.

```
>>> import re 
>>> p = '[.,!?:";()\[\]]'
>>> message = 'Whatever. you; "want:)'
>>> re.sub(p, ' ', message)
'Whatever  you  want  '
```

As stated, `replace` returns a value, does not update in-place. Same with `re.sub`, as you can see.

For related reading, see [Ways to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)